# How do i select in a concise way a group of columns in a data set in R

Tags: r

Hi i am trying to do this but in a vast data frame with hundreds of columns is there a more concise was of doing this method: df[,c(1,2,3,4,etc)] i need to write code for column 1-413 then 413- something else so it is just a range and not an assortment like [,c(1,2,5)] thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `:` instead of `-`

```
subdf <- df[2:414]
```

If we need the rowwise median

```
apply(subdf, 1, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or with `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMedians(as.matrix(subdf), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Stephen I assume that you have `data.frame` and if that is the case the `df[1:413]`  will subset the columns  from 1 to 413.  As you haven't showed any example with ` dput` or image of `str(df)`, it is hard to know the issue

Comment: @Stephen you could `edit` your post  and add an image or example data

Comment: @Stephen I think your `X`  column is the row names  and not a column

Comment: its meant to be row names thats what i mean, but its not being used as row names when running the median, i need to work out how to make it the row names instead of that numbers column. when i run the median for the rows none of the numbers given are labelled with the row names

Comment: @Stephen if you have noticed, it is character.  What is your ultimate objective

Comment: @Stephen  perhaps you dataset in csv have a column 'X' which is supposed to be row names.  If it is a column, then you can do `df[2:414]`

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by character. the objective for this part is to find the median of each row within both subsets of data i have created

Comment: @Stephen yes, try `df[2:414]` which omits the first column 'X' which is charaacter class

Comment: when doing that that leaves no row names still just numbers in the first row, that allows me to calculate the means but it doesn't matter as they aren't labelled

Comment: @Stephen What do you want as output?  You want the median or the row names.  You can label it as `setNames(apply(subdf, 1, median, na.rm = TRUE), df[[1]])`

Comment: the median of each row but it needs to be labelled? othewise i cannot say what the median for each gene is (which is what each row is)

Comment: @Stephen Please check this code `setNames(apply(subdf, 1, median, na.rm = TRUE), df[[1]])`

Comment: Here, I am a ssuming that the first column is 'X'

Comment: sorry i didnt see that, its my first time on the site